# Show that $F(x)=(x,f(x))$ is differentiable where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Show that $F(x)=(x,f(x))$ is differentiable where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is and show the matrix $dF(x)$.

This is an exercise of my homework but I'm insecurity with this. So a will write my attempt. My problem is understand how to write the matrix:

$F(x)=(x,f(x))$ is differentiable because yours components are (the professor prove that in class).

So the matrix is:

$$
dF(x)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
Id_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times k} \\
0_{k\times n} & df(x)  \\
\end{array} \right) 
$$
where
$$
df(x)=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc} 
f_1'(x)&0&\cdots&0 \\
0&f'_2(x)&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0& f'(k)
\end{array} \right)
$$

( $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_k(x))$)

Being right or wrong my thinking it would be great too someone please explain to me how I can understand intuitively the matrix of the differential, if possible indicating some online document easily accessible and didactic language.

Comment: Why don't you simply write down the Jacobian matrix of $F$? Begin with some simple case, like $n=k=1$, $n=k=2$, and so on.

Comment: The Jacobian should be $dF(x) = \begin{pmatrix}Id \\ df(x)\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: What is $f_i'(x)$? I'm not familiar with the notation.

Comment: @Travis but, $Id$ is $n\times n$ and $df(x)$ is $k\times k$, right?

Comment: @GitGud $f'_i(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x)$

Comment: @Felipe And what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x)$?This notation only makes sense to me if $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @GitGud sorry, I'm confused here! $f_i'(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial e_i}f_i(x)$ where $(e_i)$ is base of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Remember: $\frac{\partial}{\partial e_i}f_i(x)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+e_ih)-f(x)}{h}$

Comment: No, since $f$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$, $df(x)$ is a $k \times n$ matrix, with $(i, j)$ entry $$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}.$$

Comment: Felipe: what @Travis said is correct. Either your notation or your $df$ is wrong. Nitpick: Travis should have typed either $df$ instead of $df(x)$ or $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}(x)$ instead of $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}$ to be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary point $p\in{\rm dom}(f)$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $p$ we  have
$$F(p+X)-F(p)=\bigl(X,f(p+X)-f(p)\bigr)=\bigl(X,df(p).X+r(X))\bigr)\ ,$$
where
$$\lim_{X\to 0}{r(X)\over|X|}=0\ .$$
But this implies that
$$\lim_{X\to 0}
{F(p+X)-F(p)-\bigl(X,df(p).X\bigr)\over|X|}=\lim_{X\to 0}{\bigl(0,r(X)\bigr)\over|X|}=0\in{\mathbb R}^{n+k}\ ,$$
which says that
$$dF(p)=\bigl({\rm id}, \>df(p)\bigr)\ .$$
The matrix of $dF(p)$ has $n+k$ rows and $n$ columns. Its block structure is as you have printed it in your question. But the matrix of $df(p)$ appearing as the $k\times n$ lower block is not a diagonal matrix. Instead it is the matrix of the $k\cdot n$ partial derivatives $$f_{i.k}(p)={\partial f_i\over\partial x_k}(p)\ ,$$
and can have arbitrary entries.